# Use SQL geography field to initialize .NET DbGeography object

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Using Entity Framework using the `DbGeography` type as found in the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Type` package to store spatial data (just points) shows as follows in the MSSQL DB:

`0xE6100000010CAA00B9D75CA84740F4FDD478E926FA3F`

How is this hex string formatted and how can it be used to initialize a new `DbGeography` object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

I found a way to convert the HEX string to `DbGeography` by first converting it to a `SqlGeography` Type [SqlGeography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.aspx):

Make sure to add reference to: `using Microsoft.SqlServer.Types;`

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //0xE6100000010C3D7D04FEF012414034B275BA3D4E5240
        var point = "E6100000010C3D7D04FEF012414034B275BA3D4E5240";

        var pointBytes =  Enumerable.Range(0, point.Length)
                 .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                 .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(point.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                 .ToArray();


        var sqlbytes = new SqlBytes(pointBytes);


        var sqlPoint = SqlGeography.Deserialize(sqlbytes);

        Console.WriteLine("SqlGeography = {0} - {1}", sqlPoint.Lat, sqlPoint.Long);


        DbGeography newGeography = DbGeography.FromText(sqlPoint.ToString(), DbGeography.DefaultCoordinateSystemId);

        Console.WriteLine("EF DBGeography = {0} - {1}", newGeography.Latitude, newGeography.Longitude);


        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Confirmation it is correct:

[image]

Comment: You suggest using `DbGeography.FromBinary` to initialize a new `DbGeography` instance. Can you show me how this conversion works with the hex string provided? I fail to see how the provided example is relevant to the first part of your answer.

Comment: @CorstianBoerman I mean you can use any of the DbGeography extension functions to create a new instance - depending on your requirement.

Comment: If you already have a DbGeography object you can use the .FromText method as the example I have posted.

Comment: When using Entity Framework I have no problems at all working with the DbGeography type. For testing purposes whatsoever I have a CSV export from the required dataset and I want to parse this and put this in the appropriate data model, thus wanting to initialize a DbGeography object from the hex string provided.

Comment: @CorstianBoerman I think you should mention your last comment in the question so it is clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @CorstianBoerman check my Edit

Comment: Hold on a sec, I'll check it out :)

Comment: Cool! The `SqlBytes` and `SqlGeography` objects are basically what I've been searching for :) See my own answer for a little more in depth information about the storage format itself.

Answer (score 0):

The format in which MSSQL stores the geography data is defined in [[MS-SSCLRT]: Microsoft SQL Server CLR Types Serialization Formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee320529.aspx). As found on 3.1.2 in [the 5th revision](https://sqlprotocoldoc.blob.core.windows.net/productionsqlarchives/MS-SSCLRT/[MS-SSCLRT].pdf) the format is as follows:

```
0xE6100000010CAA00B9D75CA84740F4FDD478E926FA3F

SRID:                   E6 10 00 00                (4326, WGS84)
VERSION:                01 
SERIALIZATION PROPS:    0C
X (LONGITUDE):          AA 00 B9 D7 5C A8 47 40    (47.3153333333333)
Y (LATITUDE):           F4 FD D4 78 E9 26 FA 3F    (1.6345)
```

This data can be converted to a double which can be used to initialize a new DbGeography instance.

```
var x = BitConverter.ToDouble(new byte[] { 
    0xAA, 0x00, 0xB9, 0xD7, 0x5C, 0xA8, 0x47, 0x40 }, 0);

var y = ...;

DbGeography.FromText($"POINT({x} {y})");
```